# avoidable profile scope requirement

Tags: uber-api

Flow:
1. App wants to get trip info for user(s)
2. App requests all_trips scope
3. User goes through authentication flow and authorizes app for scope - gets access_token, refrech_token, scope - **No User ID**
4. User takes trip
5. webhook event sent to app-service
6. webhook event contains trip info, including user_id in meta.

To get this to work - app now needs to ask for an extra scope, which is profile, so that it can make a request to /me just to get the userid so that it can appropriately handle the event in 6.

Can the userid be included in the authentication flow? We dont need the entire profile - just the userid so that we can map the permissions to get trip details (with request/refresh token) to the webhook.

Answer (score 0):

No, today you need to request the profile scope to have access to user profile details. It will not be included in the token request.

I think you provide great feedback and it might make sense to include the uuid. Today it is not supported, but I will discuss with the team if it makes sense to change in the future.

Comment: I am aware that the extra lookup is required - hence this post :) It's completely avoidable if the uuid is included in the auth response. Again the purpose of this feedback (and the other for specifying business or personal profiles) is to give truly minimal permissions to apps. i.e. If I am using an app to share trip data for business purposes and they dont need my name and personal trip info - there should be a way to do that. Thanks again for your prompt response(s).

Comment: Well understood. I will discuss with the team and see how we can improve the endpoints.